# How can I disable all iOS notification banners while my app is being used?

Tags: ios, push-notification

A React Native-specific version of this question was asked, but not answered [React-Native: How can I disable all push notifications while my app is active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65157138/react-native-how-can-i-disable-all-push-notifications-while-my-app-is-active)

Essentially, is there a way to remove interruptions while my app is in the foreground? Ideally there would be a "focus" state I put the app into that minimizes disruptions, but I can't find an API like that.

Concretely, part of my app involves meditation states. Getting popups during one of those is distracting, so I'd like to disable banners and alerts while one of those sessions is running.

Happy to hear it's not possible, just haven't actually found that answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have an API or control over other apps notifications. But surely you can control your app notifications. You can handle those notifications without prompting. Let me know if this is helpful.